# Usando Broadcast Receiver com DownloadManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Estou aprendendo a fazer o uso do `DownloadManager` com `BroadcastReceiver` para saber quando o download está concluído.

O problema: vamos supor que vou fazer o download de 2 PDFs em uma página, eu registro 2 Receiver, ou seja, um para cada PDF, depois coloco cada um deles na fila de download (veja a chamada `dm.enqueue`). O que acontece é que para cada download concluído (status == 8) eu recebo 2 vezes essa notificação.

No aplicativo quando a página possui apenas 2 PDFs a fazer download o `dm.enqueue(request);` é chamado apenas duas vezes como esperado.

Eu pensei: a notificação de download concluído não deveria ser enviada apenas uma vez para cada arquivo?

```
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setDescription(getString(R.string.download_description));
    request.setTitle(getString(R.string.download_title));
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request
            .VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment
            .DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, uri.getLastPathSegment());
    dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context
            .DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive called");

            // http://stackoverflow.com/a/13322285/3697611
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
            q.setFilterById(extras.getLong(DownloadManager
                    .EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID));
            Cursor c = dm.query(q);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex
                        (DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));

                // se estiver completo
                if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    String uri = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex
                            (DownloadManager.COLUMN_URI));
                    String local_uri = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex
                            (DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

                    //TODO: bug, estas mensagens estão aparecendo 2
                    // vezes para cada download
                    display(getString(R.string.completed) + uri);
                    display(getString(R.string.saved) + local_uri);

                    try {

                        // quando completar o download devemos
                        // pegar o texto
                        getText(new File(new URI(local_uri)));

                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        printStackTrace(e);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager
            .ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    receivers.add(receiver);
    dm.enqueue(request);
```

[O código completo está aqui](https://bitbucket.org/guiwp/diario_oficial/src/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/officialdiary/MainActivity.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#MainActivity.java-186).

P.S.: esse é só um aplicativo bem simples que fiz para desenvolver meu conhecimento sobre o Android, atualmente ele busca PDFs na página onde publicam o diário oficial do município da cidade onde moro.

Nota: o app foi testado em um Alcatel Pixi 4'6 com Android 5.1.

## Depurando

Quando coloco um logd eu vejo as mensagens assim:

```
09-04 15:10:28.395 30024-30252/com.example.android.officialdiary D/com.example.android.officialdiary.MainActivity: download: dm.enqueue register a request
09-04 15:10:28.422 30024-30252/com.example.android.officialdiary D/com.example.android.officialdiary.MainActivity: download: dm.enqueue register a request
09-04 15:10:33.288 30024-30024/com.example.android.officialdiary D/com.example.android.officialdiary.MainActivity: download: onReceive called
09-04 15:10:33.312 30024-30024/com.example.android.officialdiary D/com.example.android.officialdiary.MainActivity: download: onReceive called
09-04 15:10:34.593 30024-30024/com.example.android.officialdiary D/com.example.android.officialdiary.MainActivity: download: onReceive called
09-04 15:10:34.609 30024-30024/com.example.android.officialdiary D/com.example.android.officialdiary.MainActivity: download: onReceive called
```

Percebemos que foram registrados dois `requests` (nesse exato momento tem 2 PDFs no portal), mas para cada um deles o onReceive foi acionado duas vezes (total deu 4/2 = 2).

Obs.: se você quer testar o código com mais rapidez basta iniciar a seção de depuração do Android Studio e quando o App começar desmarque "Extrair texto" e marque "Limpar dados" (vai apagar os PDFs baixados e fazer o download novamente mas não vai extrair o texto dos PDFs).

Answer (score 1):

O *BroadcastReceiver* está a ser registado no método `download()`.

Cada vez que o método `download()` é chamado o BroadcastReceiver é registado.

Quando o *download* terminar o *BroadcastReceiver* será chamado as vezes que foi registado.

Deverá criar e registar o *BroadcastReceiver* uma só vez no método `onCreate()`.

<sub>**Nota:** Vi que você está a usar o construtor da *Activity* para criar o *array* de *recievers*, não o use, faça isso no `onCreate()`.</sub>

Comment: obrigado pelo comentário @ramaral, veja a seção "depurando" e me diz o que acha

Comment: alterei o código, deixei de usar o construtor para inializar o array de receivers, obrigado @ramaral

Comment: Você tem de ter em conta que o método `onDestroy()` pode não ser chamado e nesse caso os BroadcastReceiver não são "desregistados". Desinstale a aplicação e volte a testar.